# Como evitar erro Max retries exceeded em raspagem em Python?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Em Python 3 fiz um programa para raspar linhas de tabela de um site público com várias páginas (97893). E crio uma lista com as linhas de cada coluna
e coloquei um `sleep` para tentar evitar que a raspagem parasse, mas mesmo usando vários tempos não está dando certo

O site inicial é este:  http://www.portaltransparencia.gov.br/PortalComprasDiretasFavorecido.asp?TipoPesquisa=2&Ano=2017&Pagina=1

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd
import random
from time import sleep

def sopa(link):
    res = requests.get(link)
    soup =  BeautifulSoup(res.text, "lxml")
    table = soup.select("table")[1]
    conjunto = table.findAll("tr")
    return conjunto

planilha = []

for i in range(1,97893):
    link = "http://www.portaltransparencia.gov.br/PortalComprasDiretasFavorecido.asp?TipoPesquisa=2&Ano=2017&Pagina="
    link = link + str(i)
    print(link)
    conjunto = sopa(link)
    sleep(random.uniform(0.2, 10))
    conta = 0
    for linha in conjunto:
        if conta > 0:
            documento = linha.find("td", {"class": "firstChild"}, {"style": "white-space: nowrap;"}).text.strip()
            nome = linha.find("a").text.strip()
            valor = linha.find("td", {"class": "colunaValor"}).text.strip()
            dicionario = {"documento": documento, "nome": nome, "valor": valor}
            planilha.append(dicionario)
        conta = conta + 1
```

Parou no site 686, com essas mensagens de erro:

```
gaierror                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
~/Documentos/Code/knight/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py in _new_conn(self)
    140             conn = connection.create_connection(
--> 141                 (self.host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw)
    142 

~/Documentos/Code/knight/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py in create_connection(address, timeout, source_address, socket_options)
     59 
---> 60     for res in socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, socket.SOCK_STREAM):
     61         af, socktype, proto, canonname, sa = res

/usr/lib/python3.6/socket.py in getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags)
    742     addrlist = []
--> 743     for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
    744         af, socktype, proto, canonname, sa = res

gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

NewConnectionError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
~/Documentos/Code/knight/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py in urlopen(self, method, url, body, headers, retries, redirect, assert_same_host, timeout, pool_timeout, release_conn, chunked, body_pos, **response_kw)
    600                                                   body=body, headers=headers,
--> 601                                                   chunked=chunked)
    602 

~/Documentos/Code/knight/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py in _make_request(self, conn, method, url, timeout, chunked, **httplib_request_kw)
    356         else:
--> 357             conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
    358 

/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py in request(self, method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
   1238         """Send a complete request to the server."""
-> 1239         self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
   1240 

/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py in _send_request(self, method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
   1284             body = _encode(body, 'body')
-> 1285         self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
   1286 

/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py in endheaders(self, message_body, encode_chunked)
   1233             raise CannotSendHeader()
-> 1234         self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
   1235 

/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py in _send_output(self, message_body, encode_chunked)
   1025         del self._buffer[:]
-> 1026         self.send(msg)
   1027 

/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py in send(self, data)
    963             if self.auto_open:
--> 964                 self.connect()
    965             else:

~/Documentos/Code/knight/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py in connect(self)
    165     def connect(self):
--> 166         conn = self._new_conn()
    167         self._prepare_conn(conn)

~/Documentos/Code/knight/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py in _new_conn(self)
    149             raise NewConnectionError(
--> 150                 self, "Failed to establish a new connection: %s" % e)
    151 

NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f4b9674a780>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

MaxRetryError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
~/Documentos/Code/knight/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/adapters.py in send(self, request, stream, timeout, verify, cert, proxies)
    439                     retries=self.max_retries,
--> 440                     timeout=timeout
    441                 )

~/Documentos/Code/knight/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py in urlopen(self, method, url, body, headers, retries, redirect, assert_same_host, timeout, pool_timeout, release_conn, chunked, body_pos, **response_kw)
    638             retries = retries.increment(method, url, error=e, _pool=self,
--> 639                                         _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
    640             retries.sleep()

~/Documentos/Code/knight/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py in increment(self, method, url, response, error, _pool, _stacktrace)
    387         if new_retry.is_exhausted():
--> 388             raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
    389 

MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='www.portaltransparencia.gov.br', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: /PortalComprasDiretasFavorecido.asp?TipoPesquisa=2&Ano=2017&Pagina=686 (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f4b9674a780>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known',))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ConnectionError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-590ac6d45255> in <module>()
      3     link = link + str(i)
      4     print(link)
----> 5     conjunto = sopa(link)
      6     sleep(random.uniform(0.2, 10))
      7     conta = 0

<ipython-input-2-7aefd26bf83b> in sopa(link)
      1 def sopa(link):
----> 2     res = requests.get(link)
      3     soup =  BeautifulSoup(res.text, "lxml")
      4     table = soup.select("table")[1]
      5     conjunto = table.findAll("tr")

~/Documentos/Code/knight/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/api.py in get(url, params, **kwargs)
     70 
     71     kwargs.setdefault('allow_redirects', True)
---> 72     return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
     73 
     74 

~/Documentos/Code/knight/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/api.py in request(method, url, **kwargs)
     56     # cases, and look like a memory leak in others.
     57     with sessions.Session() as session:
---> 58         return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
     59 
     60 

~/Documentos/Code/knight/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py in request(self, method, url, params, data, headers, cookies, files, auth, timeout, allow_redirects, proxies, hooks, stream, verify, cert, json)
    506         }
    507         send_kwargs.update(settings)
--> 508         resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
    509 
    510         return resp

~/Documentos/Code/knight/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py in send(self, request, **kwargs)
    616 
    617         # Send the request
--> 618         r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
    619 
    620         # Total elapsed time of the request (approximately)

~/Documentos/Code/knight/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/adapters.py in send(self, request, stream, timeout, verify, cert, proxies)
    506                 raise SSLError(e, request=request)
    507 
--> 508             raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
    509 
    510         except ClosedPoolError as e:

ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='www.portaltransparencia.gov.br', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: /PortalComprasDiretasFavorecido.asp?TipoPesquisa=2&Ano=2017&Pagina=686 (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f4b9674a780>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known',))
```

Por favor, será que preciso de tempos de paradas muito grandes para fazer essa raspagem? Ou pode ser falha na qualidade da minha conexão?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Corri o programa em baixo na resposta, demorou quase 2horas (mesmo com 100 threads), mas os dados estão aqui: https://we.tl/kAUuAeW9gR (não vão estar por muito tempo)

Não consigo efetivamente responder à pergunta do titulo da pergunta, porque podem ser inúmeros motivos, mas consigo ajudar a melhorar o código:

Visto que são 97893 páginas, é muito pouco viável fazer todas as requisições na mesma `thread`, mesmo que faças 1 requisição por segundo ias demorar mais de 27 horas.

Muito importante também é guardares logo num ficheiro/base de dados para não teres de executar o prog muitas mais vezes (é um programa pesado e demorado), assim da próxima que precisares dos dados basta abrires o ficheiro e as infos estão lá.

Já fiz muitos muitos webcrawlers, e quando tenho uma quantidade de requisições tão grande para fazer uso sempre threads, o que, neste caso, diminiu em muito o tempo de execução, aproveitando a parte que fizeste para efetivamente fazer parse ao html (`BeautifulSoup`), refiz algumas coisas (uso 100 threads no código abaixo):

PS: Não precisei de usar random:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd
import random
import threading, queue, json
from time import sleep

def sopa(link):
    res = requests.get(link)
    soup =  BeautifulSoup(res.text, "lxml")
    table = soup.select("table")[1]
    conjunto = table.findAll("tr")
    return conjunto

def p_manager(p_q): # funcao responsavel pelos prints aqui vai atuar o nosso p_q definido em baixo
    while True:
        msg = p_q.get()
        print(msg)
        p_q.task_done()


def handle_reqs(work):
    total_w = len(work)
    while work:
        i = work.pop(0) # fazendo assim vamos aliviando a memoria
        link = "http://www.portaltransparencia.gov.br/PortalComprasDiretasFavorecido.asp?TipoPesquisa=2&Ano=2017&Pagina={}".format(i)
        p_q.put('[+] {}/{} - getting: {}'.format(len(work), total_w, link))
        conjunto = sopa(link)
        conta = 0
        for linha in conjunto:
            if conta > 0:
                documento = linha.find("td", {"class": "firstChild"}, {"style": "white-space: nowrap;"}).text.strip()
                nome = linha.find("a").text.strip()
                valor = linha.find("td", {"class": "colunaValor"}).text.strip()
                dicionario = {"documento": documento, "nome": nome, "valor": valor}
                planilha.append(dicionario)
            conta = conta + 1
    if(threading.active_count() <= 3): # se só houverem 3 threads (esta, a main, e a daemon), acabamos o scrapping
        data_q.put(True) # acabou e enviamos o sinal para desbloquear e escrever no ficheiro

p_q = queue.Queue() # responsavel pelos prints, nao queremos sobrecarregar as outras threads com os prints (chamadas de sistema)
t = threading.Thread(target=p_manager, args=(p_q,))
t.daemon = True # daemon, significa que o programa acaba independentemente se esta tem trabalho pendente ou nao
t.start() # inicia-la

data_q = queue.Queue() # responsavel pelo rastreio do do final scrapping 
planilha = []
num_threads = 100 # vamos usar 100 threads
works = [list(range(1, 97893))[i::num_threads] for i in range(num_threads)] # preparar o trabalho para cada thread
for w in works: # dividir o trabalho pelas threads
    threading.Thread(target=handle_reqs, args=(w,)).start() # iniciar cada uma

data_q.get() # bloquear até receber o sinal e continuar o prog

with open('tests.txt', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(planilha, f, sort_keys=True, indent=4)
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pela atenção

Comment: de nada @ReinaldoChaves

Comment: Rodei o programa em minha máquina. Depois de duas horas parou no "Pagina=97845" faz um bom tempo. Não avança para o próximo link já faz cerca de 30 minutos. Pode ser problema na conexão?

Comment: Também abri o arquivo JSON que disponibilizou gentilmente. Não encontrei alguns nomes como, KATIA DALILA LIMA PROTASIO

Comment: É capaz @ReinaldoChaves... Não encontrou de ser por causa do parseamento do html, alguma página deve ter algumas tags imprevistas. Reseta o programa, tenta que comece de novo

Comment: Olá. Tudo bem? Estou tentando adaptar esse código para uma outra raspagem grande. Posso escrever a dúvida, @Miguel?

Comment: Olá @ReinaldoChaves, podes colocar outra questão e dizer-me aqui que vou tentar ajudar

Comment: Obrigado. Coloquei aqui: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/291032/em-raspagens-grandes-como-evitar-connectionerror

Comment: E aqui a tentativa com threads: https://gist.github.com/reichaves/d0b3aee99d0310f73045b20150639985