# Em raspagens grandes como evitar ConnectionError?

Tags: python, request, pandas, web-scraping

Em Python 3, eu tenho um programa para fazer web-scraping de tabelas em sites. Existem 5.299 páginas, em cada página há um tabela

Com XHR eu encontrei o JSON gerado em cada página. Mas sempre tem um erro de conexão após o programa vasculhar algumas páginas (No exemplo abaixo só pego casos do Estado "RJ"):

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import random
from time import sleep

mandados = []
i = 1


while i <= 5299:
    payload = {
    "criterio":{
        "orgaoJulgador":{
            "uf":"RJ",
            "municipio":"",
            "descricao":""
        },
        "orgaoJTR":{},
        "parte":{
            "documentos":[
                {"identificacao":""}
             ]
         }
     },
     "paginador":{"paginaAtual":i},
     "fonetica":"true",
     "ordenacao":{"porNome":False,"porData":False}
          }

    url = ('http://www.cnj.jus.br/bnmp/rest/pesquisar')

    r = requests.post(url, json=payload)
    sleep(random.uniform(0.2, 10))

    mandados.append(r.json()['mandados'])

    print("Página: ", i)
    i = i+1

df = pd.DataFrame(mandados)
df.info()

df.to_csv('mandados_12_abr_2018_RJ.csv', index=False)
```

Erro que aparece após algumas páginas:

```
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='www.cnj.jus.br', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: /bnmp/rest/pesquisar (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7fb19d8d1eb8>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known',))
```

Por favor, há alguma forma de evitar esse erro?

Com threads é possível evitar o erro?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Testando e mudando a estrutura para usar threads, são muitas pags para usar apenas uma, a não ser que tenhas tempo.

Na minha opinião ou escolhes as colunas a guardar no csv, ou fica simplesmente num ficheiro json, porque tens dados aninhados e não fica bem assim, mas isso podes ajustar depois como quiseres:
    import requests
    import pandas as pd
    import random
    import threading, queue, json
    from time import sleep

```
def get_req(i):
    url = 'http://www.cnj.jus.br/bnmp/rest/pesquisar'
    payload = {"criterio":{"orgaoJulgador":{"uf":"RJ","municipio":"","descricao":""},"orgaoJTR":{},"parte":{"documentos":[{"identificacao":""}]}},"paginador":{"paginaAtual":i},"fonetica":"true","ordenacao":{"porNome":False,"porData":False}}
    try:
        req = requests.get(url, json=payload).json()
    except Exception as err:
        print(err)
        sleep(1) # para nao 'massacrar' ainda mais o servidor, nem o nosso cpu
        return get_req(i)
    else:
        return req

def p_manager(p_q): # funcao responsavel pelos prints aqui vai atuar o nosso p_q definido em baixo
    while True:
        msg = p_q.get()
        print(msg)
        p_q.task_done()


def handle_reqs(work):
    total_w = len(work)
    while work:
        i = work.pop(0) # fazendo assim vamos aliviando a memoria
        p_q.put('[+] {}/{} - obtendo pag: {}'.format(len(work), total_w, i))
        req = get_req(i)
        for idx, i in enumerate(req['mandados']):
            for j in i['detalhes']:
               j_spl = j.split(':') # separar chave do valor
               req['mandados'][idx][j_spl[0]] = j_spl[1].strip()
        mandados.extend(req['mandados'])
    if(threading.active_count() <= 3): # se só houverem 3 threads (esta, a main, e a daemon), acabamos o scrapping
        data_q.put(True) # acabou e enviamos o sinal para desbloquear e escrever no ficheiro

p_q = queue.Queue() # responsavel pelos prints, nao queremos sobrecarregar as outras threads com os prints (chamadas de sistema)
t = threading.Thread(target=p_manager, args=(p_q,))
t.daemon = True # daemon, significa que o programa acaba independentemente se esta tem trabalho pendente ou nao
t.start() # inicia-la

data_q = queue.Queue() # responsavel pelo rastreio do do final scrapping 
mandados = []
num_threads = 100 # vamos usar 100 threads
works = [list(range(1, 5299))[i::num_threads] for i in range(num_threads)] # preparar o trabalho para cada thread
for w in works: # dividir o trabalho pelas threads
    threading.Thread(target=handle_reqs, args=(w,)).start() # iniciar cada uma

data_q.get() # bloquear até receber o sinal e continuar o prog

# print(mandados)
df = pd.DataFrame(mandados, columns=['nomeParte', 'orgao', 'numeroMandado', 'dataMandado', 'situacao', 'Nome do Genitor', 'Nome da Genitora', 'Data de nascimento', 'Carteira de identidade'])
df.to_csv('mandados_12_abr_2018_RJ.csv', index=False, sep=';')
print(df.head())
```

Ouput:

```
                            nomeParte orgao                  numeroMandado  \
0             CLAUDIA FERREIRA VIEIRA  TJRJ  358208-13.2011.8.19.0001.0002   
1  JEFFERSON FARIAS DE SOUZA ASSUNÇÃO  TJRJ  358208-13.2011.8.19.0001.0001   
2            LEANDRO MARINHO DA SILVA  TJRJ    7725-44.2011.8.19.0036.0001   
3          NEWTON SERGIO SERPA FARACO  TJRJ     935-15.2012.8.19.0002.0001   
4          FABIANO FIGUEIREDO MARQUES  TJRJ    4091-11.2012.8.19.0002.0001   

  dataMandado                situacao                   Nome do Genitor  \
0  2012-02-01  Aguardando Cumprimento              José Salema Ferreira   
1  2012-02-01  Aguardando Cumprimento     Sergio Ricardo Souza Assunção   
2  2012-02-01  Aguardando Cumprimento         Gilberto Marinho Da Silva   
3  2012-02-01  Aguardando Cumprimento            Carlos Henrique Faraco   
4  2012-02-01  Aguardando Cumprimento  Carlos Henrique Da Silva Marques   

                      Nome da Genitora Data de nascimento  \
0             Izabel Teixeira Ferreira         22/08/1973   
1                        Elaine Farias         07/01/1992   
2     Maria Das Dores Marinho Da Silva                NaN   
3                 Marilda Serpa Faraco         19/07/1979   
4  Isabel Cristina De Souza Figueiredo         17/01/1984   

  Carteira de identidade  
0              111860326  
1              246563449  
2              122077373  
3              126036201  
4              204365324
```

Comment: olá, muito obrigado. aqui levou cerca de 10 minutos. nas páginas com erro apareceu: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer')) - 
ao final gerou um CSV com as colunas: mandados, mensagem, paginador e sucesso

Comment: em mandados tem 5.298 linhas, que é a informação que me interessa. é uma lista com dicionários

Comment: acho que quando o req volta eu teria que selecionar só a informação de mandados, certo? isso é possível?

Comment: @ReinaldoChaves mas qual é a informação de mandados? Quais as colunas que te interessam?

Comment: nomeParte, orgao, numeroMandado, dataMandado, situacao e detalhes

Comment: Detalhes é uma lista, sugiro, sendo assim, para não fugir à pergunta que foi feita, que coloques outra questão para saber como fazer parse a essas colunas de maneira a teres as que te interessam. Desculpa mas eu já iria ter de alterar muito a resposta e ia ficar descontextualizada com a pergunta

Comment: Coloquei aqui: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/291062/como-criar-dataframe-em-pandas-a-partir-de-series-com-dicion%c3%a1rios , @Miguel