# Como criar dataframe em pandas a partir de series com dicionários?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Em Python3 e pandas eu tenho uma série com listas. Em cada linha da série há uma lista, com dicionários dentro. Foi obtida a partir de um arquivo:

```
import pandas as pd

geral = pd.read_csv("mandados_12_abr_2018_RJ.csv",sep=';',encoding = 'latin_1')

geral.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 5298 entries, 0 to 5297
Data columns (total 4 columns):
mandados     5298 non-null object
mensagem     0 non-null float64
paginador    5298 non-null object
sucesso      5298 non-null bool
dtypes: bool(1), float64(1), object(2)
memory usage: 129.4+ KB

mandados = geral['mandados']

mandados.reset_index().head()
index   mandados
0   0   [{'id': 409, 'numeroMandado': '2251-65.2012.8....
1   1   [{'id': 486, 'numeroMandado': '358208-13.2011....
2   2   [{'id': 100, 'numeroMandado': '2274-09.2012.8....
3   3   [{'id': 1676, 'numeroMandado': '26782-22.2012....
4   4   [{'id': 1973, 'numeroMandado': '1664656-97.201...
```

Exemplo de conteúdo de uma linha:

```
   [{'nomeParte': 'ANDRE LUIZ DE ALMEIDA', 'orgao': 'TJRJ', 
    'numeroMandado': '450429-49.2010.8.19.0001.0002', 'dataMandado': 
'2011-04-25', 'situacao': 'Aguardando Cumprimento', 'id': 4488922, 
'detalhes': ['Sexo: Masculino', 'Nome do Genitor: Jorge Carlos De 
Almeida', 'Nome da Genitora: Maria Alice Menezes', 'Nacionalidade: 
Brasileira', 'Data de nascimento: 15/11/1974', 'Carteira de identidade: 
099009730']}], 'paginador': {'mostrarProximaPagina': True, 'ultimaPagina': 
5280, 'mostrarPaginaAnterior': True, 'paginaAtual': 5278, 
'registrosPorPagina': 10, 'totalPaginas': 5300, 'primeiraPagina': 5276, 
'mostrarPaginador': True, 'totalRegistros': 52998}, 'mensagem': None}]
```

Eu desejo criar um dataframe com os itens da série em cada linha, que seriam as colunas do dataframe:

```
nomeParte, orgao, numeroMandado, dataMandado, situacao e detalhes
```

É possível fazer isso?

Comment: Quais as 'chaves' dos detalhes que queres? Não são constantes entre os dicts

Comment: Obrigado. Nome do Genitor, Nome da Genitora, Data de nascimento e Carteira de identidade

Comment: Olá Reinaldo, acredito que o problema vinha de raiz, só percebi o que realmente querias quando vi esta pergunta. Vou apagar a minha resposta aqui, acho que vais poder apagar esta pergunta pois acho que não vais ter esta duvida assim que estiver resolvida de raiz que é a melhor solução: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/291032/em-raspagens-grandes-como-evitar-connectionerror/291040#291040

Answer (score 0):

Usando o exemplo que você me deu:

```
lista = [{'nomeParte': 'ANDRE LUIZ DE ALMEIDA',
      'orgao': 'TJRJ', 
      'numeroMandado': '450429-49.2010.8.19.0001.0002',
      'dataMandado': '2011-04-25', 'situacao': 'Aguardando Cumprimento', 'id':4488922, 
      'detalhes': ['Sexo: Masculino',
                   'Nome do Genitor: Jorge Carlos De Almeida',
                   'Nome da Genitora: Maria Alice Menezes', 
                   'Nacionalidade: Brasileira',
                   'Data de nascimento: 15/11/1974',
                   'Carteira de identidade: 099009730']}]
```

Para transformar isso em um dataframe, basta usar o comando pd.DataFrame(lista)

```
import pandas as pd
b = pd.DataFrame(lista)
```

Esse comando transforma sua lista de dicionário em colunas e linhas.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]